# I am getting a strange error, google sign in is not working in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

google sign isn't working, i have added sha1 hash of the debug.store on firebase

the error is:

`I/flutter (26858): attempting to sign in
W/ActivityThread(26858): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2a59d18
I/DecorView(26858): It non-support bigbang
I/PhoneWindow(26858): isNeedChangeStatusBarColor taskInfo: [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@63810e2] size: 1
I/PhoneWindow(26858): isAPPNeedChangeSBColor pkgName: com.bitcryptorapp.jayanthl.bitcryptorapp.debug needKeep: false
I/PhoneWindow(26858): isNeedChangeStatusBarColor false
I/PhoneWindow(26858): isNeedChangeNaviBarColor taskInfo: [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@bd03c73] size: 1
I/PhoneWindow(26858): isAPPNeedChange pkgName: com.bitcryptorapp.jayanthl.bitcryptorapp.debug needKeep: false
I/PhoneWindow(26858): isNeedChangeNaviBarColor false
I/PhoneWindow(26858): generateLayout mNavigationBarColor: ff000000
I/PhoneWindow(26858): generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0`

firebase_auth version: ^0.6.6
google_sign_in version: ^3.2.4

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake i had wrong google-services version number in the dependencies -> classpath, now i have changed it to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`